# Boost Geometry: Templating BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_BOX_2D_4VALUES

Tags: boost, boost-geometry

I would like to use R-tree in the Boost Geometry package to construct a spatial index. I would like to use my own Box (CRectangle) data structure as I'm using a third-party library for polygon operations.

To begin, I followed this tutorial on registering custom point/box types. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/adapted/register/boost_geometry_register_box_2d_4values.html

I arrived at the following (simplified) code, which works OK. I get a correct area of 4.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/index/rtree.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/box.hpp>

namespace bg  = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;

struct dummy_pt
{
    int x,y;
};

class CRectangle
{
 private:
   int xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax;

 public:
   // implementation not shown.
   int xmin();
   int ymin();
   int xmax();
   int ymax();
}

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D(dummy_pt, int, bg::cs::cartesian, x, y)
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_BOX_2D_4VALUES(CRectangle, dummy_pt, xmin(), ymin(), xmax(), ymax())

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    CRectangle x = bg::make<CRectangle>(0,0,2,2);
    std::cout << "Area: " << bg::area(x) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is how do I register CRectangle if it is templated? That is,

```
template <typename T>
class CRectangle 
{
  public:
    T xmin();
    T xmax();
    T ymin();
    T ymax();

  private: 
    T xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax;
}
```

Here, I could use:

```
CRectangle<int> or CRectangle<double>
```

I know there is 
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_BOX_TEMPLATED() but that requires lowerLeft() and upperRight() functions. In my case, the CRectangle class will not have these methods since it is coming form a third-party library.

I could write a subclass and provide these two methods, but I would like to know if it possible to use templated classes with BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_BOX_2D_4VALUES or some other simple way?

Thank you for any suggestions/ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I should have done more investigation. The following code snippet worked! I just registered both possibilities:

```
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D(dummy_pt, int, bg::cs::cartesian, x, y)
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_BOX_2D_4VALUES(CRectangle<int>, dummy_pt, xmin(), ymin(), xmax(), ymax())
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_BOX_2D_4VALUES(CRectangle<double>, dummy_pt, xmin(), ymin(), xmax(), ymax())

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    CRectangle<int> x = bg::make<CRectangle<int>> (0,0,2,2);
    CRectangle<double> y = bg::make<CRectangle<double>> (0,0,3,3);
    std::cout << "Area: " << bg::area(x) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Area: " << bg::area(y) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'd still be interested if there is a better solution than brute forcing.

Comment: Just expand the macros. It'll define a (small) set of traits. Use partial template specializations to define them generically. Job done.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not very good with template programming. Can you provide a small example to make it more clear?

Comment: Sorry. In that case, your work around seems just fine. Why do you want me to do things you don't want to? You can always come to SO with concrete questions if you get stuck.